# Is by default MySQL 5.7 supports every query as a transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions, myisam

I have a system which uses Perl scripts to load data from xml files into MySQL database to generate some reports.
Previously it used MySQL 5.1 and I have now a requirement to upgrade to MySQL 5.7.

In both cases, i have mysql auto-commit=1(as default config only) and perl auto-commit=0(in my script before running an sql - only for inserts im having explicit commit statements)

After the upgrade, the new tables will be created with InnoDB as its the default engine, and as I did not want transaction management and change my tables from MyISAM to InnoDB, I have suppressed the usage using the below flags in .my.cnf
**default-storage-engine=MyISAM**
**disabled-storage-engines=InnoDB**
After making the changes above I was able to achieve table creation of MyISAM engine but still looks like transaction management is some how enabled(which is my guess) and I face the below issue

```
mysql> show full processlist;
+----+------+-----------+---------+---------+------+---------------------------------+----------------------------+
| Id | User | Host      | db      | Command | Time | State                           | Info                       |
+----+------+-----------+---------+---------+------+---------------------------------+----------------------------+
| 14 | test | localhost | REGRESS | Sleep   |   17 |                                 | NULL                       |
| 15 | test | localhost | REGRESS | Query   |   16 | Waiting for table metadata lock | OPTIMIZE TABLE TEST.SOURCE |
| 16 | test | localhost | NULL    | Query   |    0 | starting                        | show full processlist      |
+----+------+-----------+---------+---------+------+---------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

The only way I'm sure this not because of table locking because I have not faced this issue with MySQL 5.1 where I used "skip-innodb" option and default storage engine is MyISAM.

I was unable to get any official document which says that transactions are by default enabled in MySQL 5.7. It would be great if someone one can confirm the same. As even after having the tables (as in my case) using MyISAM engine, still, it looks like it takes every query as a transaction which is what the issue is I suspect.

Do let me know if more information is needed.

Is there any way I can disable transaction management in MySQL 5.7 by setting some env variable?

Is there by any way we can disable InnoDB engine apart from above flag set?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi again :-) As mentioned in the comments to your last question (maybe not clearly enough), the meta locks also apply to MyISAM, even if they are not transactional. I added an answer for some details about that. You forgot to mention that you `set autocommit = 0` in your script (and want to be able to keep doing that), which is a really important detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

[Metadata locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/metadata-locking.html), introduced in MySQL 5.5 (which is why it couldn't interfer in your script in 5.1), prevents ddl changes while a different transaction is active:

> The server achieves this by acquiring metadata locks on tables used within a transaction and deferring release of those locks until the transaction ends. A metadata lock on a table prevents changes to the table's structure. This locking approach has the implication that **a table that is being used by a transaction within one session cannot be used in DDL statements by other sessions until the transaction ends.**

For your case, it is important to note that this also includes MyISAM-tables, even if they are not transactional:

> This principle applies not only to transactional tables, but also to nontransactional tables.

So even if you use "just" a MyISAM table in a transaction, you cannot alter that table until the transaction ends. Transactions are started either by `start transaction` or if you disable `autocommit`. Autocommit is [enabled by default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit), with the effect that

> In autocommit mode, each statement is in effect a complete transaction, so metadata locks acquired for the statement are held only to the end of the statement.

So while transactions are not by default enabled in MySQL 5.7, if you disable `autocommit` (which is what you do in your script), a transaction will implicitly start. And while this transaction has no effect on queries on MyISAM-tables, it will, as of MySQL 5.5, still add the metadata lock and thus have an effect on ddl-statements (in *other* sessions). If you do not want that, do not disable autocommit.

What you cannot do (if that is what you are after) is to disable the "transaction functionality" altogether by disabling InnoDB. InnoDB is a storage engine. In contrast to MyISAM, it supports transactions, but it's not the transaction-feature itself - although there certainly is a very big co-dependency, as without a main storage engine that supports transactions, that feature would have not that much value. The [transactional concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) is an integral part of [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) and cannot be disabled - which is so fundamental that the documentation will (as far as I know) not even explicitly state that.

Answer (score 0):

With MyISAM, you can do multiple *reads* on the same table at the same time.  But doing anything else locks the table.  Staying with MyISAM is wrong; you should be working on moving to InnoDB.  MyISAM is being deprecated in the release after 5.7.

MyISAM has no "transactions".  For example, if the server crashes in the middle of a multi-row `UPDATE`, some of the rows will be committed to the table; some will not be.  This violates a main tenet of "transactions".